# Ipywidgets interact function in google colab creates new plots instead of updating the desired plots

Tags: python, matplotlib, google-colaboratory, ipywidgets

I recently created a plot using ipywidgets. The goal was to display data in a stacked barplot and to have two dropdown menus to select the start and end month for the plot, each bar representing data for one month. I was pretty happy with the result since everything worked until I restarted my colab notebook two days after. Now running the code first returns the correct output with the two dropdown menus but the selection of either month results in a new plot, being created underneath the first one.

I spent a lot of time trying to fix it, using `clear_output()` in multiple ways, creating the matplotlib figure outside the function, and restarting the kernel but I just couldn't change the way it behaves. Does anyone have a solution to this?

I am new to `ipywidgets`, so if my approach is fundamentally incorrect, please don't hesitate to guide me in a more promising direction.

```py
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt
import ipywidgets as widgets
from IPython.display import display
from IPython.display import clear_output

def minute(pd_datetime):
  return int(pd_datetime.total_seconds() / 60)

#This data is created just for the sake of a minimal example and I hope this works:
start_limit=pd.to_datetime("2019-09-01",utc=True)
end_limit=pd.to_datetime("2023-05-01",utc=True)
num_minutes = int((end_limit - start_limit).total_seconds() / 60)

numbers = numbers = np.random.randint(0, 100, size=(num_minutes, 1), dtype=np.uint16)
time = np.array([start_limit + dt.timedelta(minutes=i) for i in range(numbers.shape[0])])
numbers_df = pd.DataFrame(numbers)
numbers_df.index = time

output = widgets.Output()
clear_output()

# define function to update plot based on selected months
def update_plot_monthly_usage(start_limit, end_limit, min_month, max_month):
  clear_output(wait=True)

  fig1=plt.figure(figsize=(10,6))
  ax1=fig1.add_subplot(111)
  # convert selected months to start and end timestamps
  start = pd.to_datetime(min_month + '-01',utc=True)
  end = pd.to_datetime(max_month + '-01',utc=True) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(1)


  # filter data based on selected months
  ind1 = max(minute(start-start_limit),0)
  ind2 = min(int((end-start_limit).total_seconds()/60),int((end_limit-start_limit).total_seconds()/60))
  
  # group data by month and sum
  
 
  monthly_data = numbers_df.iloc[ind1:ind2].groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='M'))
  months=monthly_data.ngroups
  monthly_data = monthly_data.sum()/60 #hours

  
  # plot the data in the subplot

  if months>=10:
    ax1.bar(monthly_data.sum(axis=1).index, monthly_data.sum(axis=1),width=20) #Purely cosmetic
  else:
    ax1.bar(pd.date_range(start=min_month+'-01', end=max_month+'-01', freq='MS').strftime('%Y-%m'), monthly_data.sum(axis=1))
  
  ax1.set_xlabel('Month')
  ax1.set_ylabel('Total usage in hours')
  ax1.set_title('Platform usage for selected months')


# create dropdown widgets for selecting months
min_month = widgets.Dropdown(options=pd.date_range(start='2019-09-01', end='2023-01-01', freq='MS').strftime('%Y-%m'), description='Min Month')
max_month = widgets.Dropdown(options=pd.date_range(start='2019-10-01', end='2023-02-01', freq='MS').strftime('%Y-%m'), description='Max Month')

# create interactive plot
widgets.interact(update_plot_monthly_usage, start_limit=widgets.fixed(start_limit), end_limit=widgets.fixed(end_limit), min_month=min_month, max_month=max_month)
display(output)
```

In the colab notebook, I have several other plots that work pretty much the same, it was also a question if I need to change any of the names in order to run the whole notebook, as I have to run every cell separately at the moment, for it to display anything. I suspected the reason was the widgets "min_month" and "max_month" having the same name in all of the cells but this is a side question of minor importance. I excluded the stacked barplots here.

As said above, I tried making it work using clear_output(), it however doesn't clear the output. Equally clear_output() doesn't work if used outside of the interact function, at the end of the code. Another suggestion I followed was putting the whole function into a "with output:" statement but this didn't change any of the behavior so I excluded it.

Comment: I have confirmed this behavior in Google Colab. The given code correctly updates the given figure when using jupyter lab.

Comment: This is a new bug. I have used interactive successfully in a notebook for 5 years until this unexpected behavior started.

Comment: Same issue, though it doesn't work with Jupyter Lab either. Jupyter Lab and Dataspell don't update the plot at all. Colab at least produces some output.

Comment: Juypter Notebook with ipympl behaves just like Colab.

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue yesterday and found a solution in [an example notebook for ipywidgets](https://colab.research.google.com/github/jupyter-widgets/ipywidgets/blob/master/docs/source/examples/Using%20Interact.ipynb) on the section about update flickering.  I noticed that there was a `plt.show()` command at the end of the update function, and adding that too my code was enough to prevent the continual addition of new plots.  I tested it on the code you posted as well and it seems to sort things out there too.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34607382)

Answer (score 0):

The solution is same as the one suggested by @VDB but for the sake of completness I am adding an example, from the link suggested in the answer.

```
%matplotlib inline
from ipywidgets import interactive
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np

def f(m, b):
    plt.figure(2)
    x = np.linspace(-10, 10, num=1000)
    plt.plot(x, m * x + b)
    plt.ylim(-5, 5)
    plt.show() # This is part that needs to be added to fix the issue

interactive_plot = interactive(f, m=(-2.0, 2.0), b=(-3, 3, 0.5))
output = interactive_plot.children[-1]
output.layout.height = '350px'
interactive_plot
```